Comparing the density of primes in intervals
Let $\pi(N)$ be the counting function of the primes equal to or smaller than $N$. Three statements (conjectures):

For any $N \geq T_1$ holds $\quad E_1 = \Big(\pi(N) - \pi(\frac{2}{3}N)\Big) - \frac{1}{3}\pi(N) < 0$
For any $N \geq T_2$ holds $\quad E_2 = \Big(\pi(\frac{2}{4}N) - \pi(\frac{2}{5}N)\Big) - \frac{1}{10}\pi(N) < 0$
For any $N \geq T_3$ holds $\quad E_3 = \Big(\pi(N) - \pi(\frac{2}{3}N)\Big) + \Big(\pi(\frac{2}{4}N) - \pi(\frac{2}{5}N)\Big) - \Big(\frac{1}{10}\pi(N) + \frac{1}{3}\pi(N)\Big) < 0$

I have checked the above statements numerically up to $2.5 \times 10^5$. My results:
Statement (1): true for all values of $124 < N \leq 2.5 \times 10^5$.
Statement (2): not to say if it's true of false. $E_2$ 'wobbles around' 0
Statement (3): true for all values of $176 < N \leq 2.5 \times 10^5$.
As far as I understand statement (1) must (also) be true for all $N \geq 2.5 \times 10^5$, as the density of the primes in the range $\{1,\dots,\frac{2}{3}N\}$, by average, is higher than the density of the primes in range $ \{ \frac{2}{3}N,\dots,N \} $.
Statement 2 seems not correct for small values of $N_2$. Is there a value $N_2$ above statement 2 is always correct?
And what about statement 3? Intuitively I would say that $|E_1| > |E_2|$ and so statement 3 is true for all $N > 176$. Is that correct?

Your first two statements are of the form
$$
\pi(\beta n)-\pi(\alpha n)-(\beta-\alpha)\pi(n) < 0
$$
for $n$ sufficiently large, with some constants $0<\alpha<\beta\le1$. It follows from the prime number theorem and the expansion of the logarithmic integral that
$$
\pi(\beta n)-\pi(\alpha n)-(\beta-\alpha)\pi(n) = (\alpha\log\alpha-\beta\log\beta)\frac{n}{\log^2n} + O\left(\frac{n}{\log^3n}\right).
$$
Note that $\frac23\log\frac23 - 1\log1 = -0.27\ldots$ and $\frac25\log\frac25 - \frac12\log\frac12 = -0.019\ldots$ are both negative, so #1 and #2 are true eventually. (The latter is small in magnitude, hence your difficulty working with that case.)
You could go through a similar tedious calculation for #3 that would probably show the same. You could even take the calculation to third order terms which would let you estimate the crossover point.
Edit: I have done the third calculation and indeed it holds for large enough numbers. Its asymptotic is about $-0.2902n/\log^2n$.
